# Segmentation fault after reducing max-page-size

Tags: gcc

Gcc has an option max-page-size. I found the executable size is reduced when I reduce this value.
-Wl,-z,max-page-size=128, the default is 4906 on x86_64. Though gcc allows me to reduce it , the final exec can't run at all.

Comment: Is this question about Linux and ELF?